# Regex, every non-alphanumeric character except white space or colon

Tags: regex

How can I do this one anywhere?

Basically, I am trying to match all kinds of miscellaneous characters such as ampersands, semicolons, dollar signs, etc.

Comment: `/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s\:]*/`

Comment: /[^a-zA-Z0-9\s\:]+/   - your star matches on 0

Answer (score 400, accepted):

```
[^a-zA-Z\d\s:]
```

- \d - numeric class
- \s - whitespace
- a-zA-Z - matches all the letters
- ^ - negates them all - so you get - non numeric chars, non spaces and non colons

Comment: That's what I was looking at also :)) - I have to promote your perfect answer

Comment: The only thing that I found is that this removes special characters like é or ã. I would prefer [^\w\d\s:].

Comment: Downvoted because this will not catch non-Latin characters, nor "special" Latin characters.

Comment: `\d` and `\s` are Perl extensions which are typically not supported by older tools like `grep`, `sed`, `tr`, `lex`, etc.

Comment: Another answer that's only useful for English or other Latin-based languages without accents. I think the world is a wee bit larger than that :). Downvoted.

Comment: Just to counter the criticism of this answer, my intention was to find all "special" non-ascii letters so this worked perfectly.

Comment: What's the `:` for?

Answer (score 47):

This should do it:

```
[^a-zA-Z\d\s:]
```

Comment: The rest either check for space but not whitespace or have the negation in the wrong spot to actually negate.

Comment: \w catches underscores also - which is a non-alphanumeric character

Comment: Aha! I shall modify -- I didn't know that. I expect it works differently for different engines, but might as well give the OP the safe answer.

Comment: Downvoted because this will not catch non-Latin characters, nor "special" Latin characters.

Comment: @damian, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/73853673/4575331

Answer (score 29):

If you want to treat accented latin characters (eg. à Ñ) as normal letters (ie. avoid matching them too), you'll also need to include the appropriate Unicode range ([\u00C0-\u00FF](http://jrgraphix.net/r/Unicode/00A0-00FF)) in your regex, so it would look like this:

```
/[^a-zA-Z\d\s:\u00C0-\u00FF]/g
```

- `^` negates what follows
- `a-zA-Z` matches upper and lower case letters
- `\d` matches digits
- `\s` matches white space (if you only want to match spaces, replace this with a space)
- `:` matches a colon
- `\u00C0-\u00FF` matches the Unicode range for accented latin characters.

nb. Unicode range matching might not work for all regex engines, but the above certainly works in Javascript (as seen in [this pen](http://codepen.io/blucube/pen/FmGel) on Codepen).

nb2. If you're not bothered about matching underscores, you could replace `a-zA-Z\d` with `\w`, which matches letters, digits, and underscores.

Comment: This range contains some characters which are not alphanumeric (U+00D7 and U+00F7), and excludes a lot of valid accented characters from non-Western languages like Polish, Czech, Vietnamese etc.

Comment: Upvoted for the description of each part of the RegEx.

Answer (score 16):

Try this:

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9 :]
```

JavaScript example:

```
"!@#$%* ABC def:123".replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 :]/g, ".")
```

See a online example:

http://jsfiddle.net/vhMy8/

Comment: Downvoted because this will not catch non-Latin characters, nor "special" Latin characters.

Comment: It is easy to down vote an answer, and yet more difficult to provide constructive information to the board, e.g. how does one then catch non-Latin characters, nor "special" Latin characters? As of my count to here you have down voted 3 answers for the same reason, and in my opinion for a rather minor tweak. For example, I am here to find a regex for exactly what is discussed in these answers. I don't care about character sets that will not be used in my application. Law of diminishing returns.

Comment: Aaron might be a "minor tweak" to a US citizen, but highly relevant for... the rest of this planet.

Comment: `[^a-zA-Z0-9 :]` can be replaced with `[^\w:]`

Comment: `\w` includes underscores also, so keep an eye on that

Comment: @ user3842449  `I don't care about character sets that will not be used in my application.` Well, that's quite self-centric. Moreover, the question of the OP was to remove whitespaces, so this should answer this question. For pretty much all non-English languages, it doesn't.

Answer (score 7):

In JavaScript:

`/[^\w_]/g`

`^` negation, i.e. select anything *not* in the following set

`\w` any word character (i.e. any alphanumeric character, plus underscore)

`_` negate the underscore, as it's considered a 'word' character

Usage example - `const nonAlphaNumericChars = /[^\w_]/g;`

Comment: `[^\w_]` is the same as `[^\w]` (as `_` is a word char), and it is equal to `\W`.

Answer (score 5):

No alphanumeric, white space or '_'.

```
var reg = /[^\w\s)]|[_]/g;
```

Answer (score 5):

If you mean "non-alphanumeric characters", try to use this:

```
var reg =/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g      //[^abc]
```

Answer (score 2):

This regex works for [C#](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_%28programming_language%29), [PCRE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions) and [Go](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Go_%28programming_language%29) to name a few.

It doesn't work for JavaScript on Chrome from what [RegexBuddy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RegexBuddy) says. But there's already an example for that here.

This main part of this is:

`\p{L}`

which represents `\p{L}` or `\p{Letter}` any kind of letter from any language.`

---

**The full regex itself:** `[^\w\d\s:\p{L}]`

**Example:** https://regex101.com/r/K59PrA/2

Comment: This is the only answer here which deals correctly with Unicode accented alphabetics in a proper way. Sadly, not all regex engines support this facility (even Python lacks it, as of 3.8, even though its regex engine is ostensibly PCRE-based).

Comment: I'll remove Python from the answer, I thought I tested that but apparently not. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

Previous solutions only seem reasonable for English or other Latin-based languages without accents, etc. Those answers are for that reason not generalised to answer the question.

According to the [Whitespace character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character) article on Wikipedia, these are all the whitespace characters in Unicode:

U+0009, U+000A, U+000B, U+000C, U+000D, U+0020, U+0085, U+00A0, U+1680, U+180E, U+2000, U+2001, U+2002, U+2003, U+2004, U+2005, U+2006, U+2007, U+2008, U+2009, U+200A, U+200B, U+200C, U+200D, U+2028, U+2029, U+202F, U+205F, U+2060, U+3000, U+FEFF

So in my opinion, the most inclusive solution would be (might be slow, but this is about accuracy):

```
\u0009\u000A\u000B\u000C\u000D\u0020\u0085\u00A0\u1680\u180E\u2000\u2001\u2002\u2003\u2004\u2005\u2006\u2007\u2008\u2009\u200A\u200B\u200C\u200D\u2028\u2029\u202F\u205F\u2060\u3000\uFEFF
```

Thus, to answer OP's question to include "every non-alphanumeric character except white space or colon", prepend a hat `^` to *not* include above characters and add the colon to that, and surround the regex in `[` and `]` to instruct it to 'any of these characters':

```
"[^:\u0009\u000A\u000B\u000C\u000D\u0020\u0085\u00A0\u1680\u180E\u2000\u2001\u2002\u2003\u2004\u2005\u2006\u2007\u2008\u2009\u200A\u200B\u200C\u200D\u2028\u2029\u202F\u205F\u2060\u3000\uFEFF]"
```

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/H65LfiV27qTcJbR0)

---

Bonus: solution for R

```r
trimws2 <- function(..., whitespace = "[\u0009\u000A\u000B\u000C\u000D\u0020\u0085\u00A0\u1680\u180E\u2000\u2001\u2002\u2003\u2004\u2005\u2006\u2007\u2008\u2009\u200A\u200B\u200C\u200D\u2028\u2029\u202F\u205F\u2060\u3000\uFEFF]") {
  trimws(..., whitespace = whitespace)
}
```

This is even faster than trimws() itself which sets " \t\n\r".

```r
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(trimws2(" \t\r\n"), trimws(" \t\r\n"))
#> Unit: microseconds
#>                   expr    min     lq     mean  median      uq     max neval cld
#>  trimws2(" \\t\\r\\n") 29.177 29.875 31.94345 30.4990 31.3895 105.642   100  a 
#>   trimws(" \\t\\r\\n") 45.811 46.630 48.25076 47.2545 48.2765 116.571   100   b
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the regex to consider accented latin characters (eg. à é à ù) as special characters. Use this regex:

```
[^a-zà-ýA-ZÀ-Ý0-9\s\:]*
```

[REGEX DEMO](https://tools.waytolearnx.com/regex-tester/c19bf6e48a3a).

Answer (score -3):

Try to add this:

```
^[^a-zA-Z\d\s:]*$
```

This has worked for me... :)

Comment: This seems to repeat the accepted answer from 2011. The `^` and `$` anchors confines it to match entire lines and the `*` quantifier means it also matches empty lines.

Answer (score -3):

[^\w\s-]

Character set of characters which not:

- Alphanumeric
- Whitespace
- Colon