# Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: Nothing to repeat

Tags: javascript, regex

Here is my regex:

```
var newRegexp= new RegExp('\[\/\[\]\^\$\|\*\+\(\)\\~@#%&\-_+=\{}£<>]{1,}', 'g');
```

I get the `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: Nothing to repeat` error with it, and I can't figure out why. I used it on [RegExr](http://regexr.com/) and it works fine. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: what is the regex you are looking for

Comment: I need to check for special characters on an input field in html. onkeydown

Comment: [Something like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6053541/regex-every-non-alphanumeric-character-except-white-space-or-colon) is probably easier to maintain then.

Comment: @Cerbrus would that work for non-latin languages though?

Comment: Good point. I have no idea.

Comment: @MatthewWren: no it will not work for non latin characters, however you can use the same idea: building a negated character class with all the allowed characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an escaped first `[` that is supposed to start a range. Unescape it.

Also mind that it is better to use a literal notation (I also suggest removing unnecessary escaping as it makes the regex too unreadable):

```
var newRegexp = /[\/\[\]^$|*+()\\~@#%&_+={}£<>-]+/g;
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/nY1sA7/2)

Also note that I replaced `{1,}` with `+` as it is shorter and means absolutely the same. If we put the hyphen at the end of the character class, we do not have to escape it.

Comment: Pet peeve: no space before the `=` sign ;-) Still, nice answer, fixes more than just the immediate problem. +1

Comment: I have added the space for better aesthetic feel :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to double escape the `\` like, also inside `[]` there is no need escape most of the regex special characters

```
new RegExp('[/\\[\\]^$|*+()~@#%&\\-_+={}£<>]{1,}', 'g');
```