# php preg_replace all but alphanumeric, space and accented letters

Tags: php, preg-replace, non-ascii-characters

I want to strip a string from all characters, except for: Alphanumeric characters, spaces and accented letters.

I got it to work for everything except for the accented letters:

```
$fname = preg_replace("/[^\w\space/", "", $fname);
```

What do I need to change in order to allow accented letters in the output?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58959333/2943403

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I was struggling to get things working, I found the answer myself, so I decided to share it with you:

```
$fname = preg_replace("/[^\w\space\pL]/", "", $fname);
```

The "pL" part matches anything in the Unicode letter category, so accented letters are allowed in the output.

Answer (score 0):

i found solution.

**Accented letter**

```
$str = 'paulraâj píc - accountant and knows Bilingüe';
```

**Removing Accented letter**

```
echo '<br>' .preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_ -]/s', '', $str);
```

**Result : paulraj pc - accountant and knows Bilinge**
wow works great
Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Please use this one :

```
$fname = preg_replace("/[^ \w]+/", "", $fname);
```

Comment: Please give some explanation around why that code is better and how it works to give more context to you answer