# I'm looking for a regex to detect special characters in javascript so I can show a validation error

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm looking for a regex to detect special characters in javascript.

current attempt doesnt cater for all special characters:

```
        this.validateSpecialCharacters = (valueA): boolean => {
            const regex = /[~`!#$%\^&*+=\-\[\]\\';,/{}|\\":<>\?]/;
            return regex.test(valueA);
        };
```

Does anyone have a better regex to cater for all english keyboard special characters e.g. @!"£$%^&*() etc

Comment: What if you just did a Regex for *not alpha-numeric*, rather than trying to list out all special characters? [http://stackoverflow.com/a/6053606/2026606](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6053606/2026606)

Comment: Define "special". Punctuation? Non-alphanumeric? Not-used-in-everyday-conversation? "What's this called?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are matching every special character, it's better to just tell the regex to not match alphanumeric characters.

```
const regex = /[^A-Za-z0-9]/
```

You can add any other cases inside the `[]`. This regex will match anything that is not included inside the `[]`.