# Regex: Match all words in list, ignoring special characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to highlight a specific paragraph in a large body of text using regex. The issue is the text I need to highlight has had some special characters removed, so I'm having trouble writing a regex to find the match in the body. I started by pulling out all the whole words from the string I need to find, like so:

- Starting string: "Hello, this is my search string"
- Resulting string: "Hello this is my search string"

I'm now trying to match the resulting string in the body, but since the body still has some special characters (which I can't remove for display purposes) I am having difficulty with the regex.

- Body: "This is the body, where you can find lots of special characters. Hello, "this" is my search string without the correct punctuation."

How can I match this sentence? **Hello this is my search string** and ignore the extra characters in the body?

Comment: what do you consider special characters

Comment: anything that is not a number or a letter

Comment: you can just remove the "special characters" using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6053541/regex-every-non-alphanumeric-character-except-white-space-or-colon)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regular Expression for alphanumeric and underscores](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336210/regular-expression-for-alphanumeric-and-underscores)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this `[^\w\d\s]` - here is [example](https://regex101.com/r/hmipM0/2)

You can use following [code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2295681/860099) to find index of "spacial characters" (as you describe in comment below question *"anything that is not a number or a letter"*, I guess that "space" is not special too) appear:

```
let str = 'Body: "This is the body, where you can find lots of special characters. Hello, "this" is my search string without the correct punctdsuation."'

let re = /[^\w\d\s]/g;

while ((match = re.exec(str)) != null) 
{
    console.log("match found at " + match.index);
}
```

Here is working [EXAMPLE](https://jsfiddle.net/upv9dah6/)

Comment: I don't want to modify the body to do the match. I need to keep the special characters in because they are being displayed. For example, the body may contain "$3" and I don't need to strip that out.

Comment: @lamills526 You can first make copy of string - and then remove characters in one copy only.

Comment: If I make a copy, then find a match, I won't be able to highlight in the original body. Which is my main goal