# RegEx: Find all lines that contain non alphabet characters?

Tags: grep, sublimetext3

I am using the RegEx search tool in [Sublime](https://www.sublimetext.com/). 
I need to select all lines that contain non alphabet characters (excluding spaces).

E.g.

```
Hedgehog's shoes
The Fox Machine
The Armadillo`s wish
```

In the above, the entirety of hedgehog and armadillo lines would be selected, because they contain non alphabet characters.  The fox line would not be selected.

Here is my code:

```
.*[^a-zA-Z\s]
```

Explanation

```
.* - Selects string
[^] - Ignore everything in the square brackets
a-zA-Z - Ignores all alphabet characters 
\s - Ignores Space
```

That should work in theory, but [it doesn't](https://regex101.com/r/K59PrA/6). It only selects everything up to the offending character, but nothing after it.

Please note, I am looking for a solution that works in Sublime's Find and Replace. If this is not possible in Sublime, then how can I adapt the code so I can search an entire directory of files via the MacOS terminal?

I think doing it in the terminal would be

```
for f in *; do '.*[^a-zA-Z\s]'
```

But that doesn't work either.

PS. There are questions about this on Stackoverflow already ([Such as this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6053541/regex-every-non-alphanumeric-character-except-white-space-or-colon)). But they only deal with selecting the individual characters and not the whole line.

Comment: You could match the rest of the line `.*[^a-zA-Z\s].*` https://regex101.com/r/8jvhel/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using

```
.*[^[:alpha:]\s].*
.*[^[:alpha:][:space:]].*
```

**Details**

- `.*` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
- `[^[:alpha:]\s]` / `[^[:alpha:][:space:]]`  - any char but an alphabetic or whitespace char
- `.*` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible

See the SublimeText demo:

[image]

Note you may use `[^[:alpha:][:space:]]` in MacOS terminal with `grep`:

```
grep '[^[:alpha:][:space:]]' file
```

See [an online demo](https://ideone.com/XUFaTy).

Comment: `Note you may use [^[:alpha:][:space:]] in MacOS terminal with grep:` When I try that on a directory of files, it says "grep: file: No such file or directory" Thanks for any help you can offer!

Comment: `grep '[^[:alpha:][:space:]]' file` will work. If you want to run on some files, you may use `for f in *.your_extension; do grep '[^[:alpha:][:space:]]' "$f"; done`. Instead of `*.your_extension`, you may any other glob pattern to get the files you need.

Comment: @big_smile To recursively use `grep` to search in the current directory, you may use `grep -R '[^[:alpha:][:space:]]' .`. See [this thread](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/275373/how-to-make-grep-work-like-in-ubuntu/275379). Note that in a lot of cases when it comes to using POSIX tools in MacOS, it is recommended to install and use their GNU versions.

Comment: Thanks! One last question, in the terminal, if I want to replace the found line (or delete the line), how would I do that. I thought it would be  `for f in *.txt; do grep '[^[:alpha:][:space:]]/d' "$f"; done` with the `/d` standing for the replacement (in this case delete), but it just says `grep: invalid character class`

Comment: @big_smile You do that with `sed`: `for f in *.txt; do sed -i '' '/[^[:alpha:][:space:]]/d' "$f"; done` - note it will remove the lines inline due to `i` option (the`''` is required in a FreeBSD sed). In GNU `sed`, you do not need the `''` after `-i`.

Answer (score 1):

The pattern you tried first matches until the end of the line and will backtrack to match one of `[^a-zA-Z\s]`

There is nothing after that pattern so the match will stop there.

As you already have you match, you could match the rest of the line using

```
.*[^a-zA-Z\s].*
```